# how to close a limit long Order? close a position at a certain price

Tags: python

Please tell me how to do without a stop limit without a stop loss exactly as in the photo, close the long? The order must be a limit order!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq8yz.jpg)

I enter the order like this:

```
order = client.futures_create_order(
    symbol = symbol,
    side = 'BUY',
    positionSide = "LONG",
    type = 'LIMIT',
    timeInForce = "GTC",
    quantity = quantity,
    price = '1955'
    )
```

I am interested in the futures on the binance